# What's this inadvertent thing?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Try to find out which word is hidden in this riddle:

A flat and sharp item
occurring inadvertently
and sometimes in a twin pack
it's altering what will come
and can be naturally erased.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd say the word is...

> **[accidental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_(music))**

Reasoning:

A flat and sharp item

> [Flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_(music)) and [sharp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_(music)) are types of accidentals in music.

occurring inadvertently

> Inadvertent being a synonym of accidental.

and sometimes in a twin pack

> There are [double accidentals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_(music)#Double_accidentals).

it's altering what will come

> They raise or lower the pitch of the next note.

and can be naturally erased.

> A [natural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_(music)) is an accidental that cancels previous accidentals.

Comment: Correct answer. Nice that you linked all relevant parts of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

the inadvertent thing is

> spell check marker

A flat and sharp item

> shows as a relatively flat and pointy zigzag in most word processors

occurring inadvertently

> only appears when you make a mistake

and sometimes in a twin pack

> mistakes in both spelling (red) and grammar (green) can appear at the same time

it's altering what will come

> an edit to the text will surely follow when this marker appears...

and can be naturally erased.

> ... after which the marker will automatically disappear

Comment: something naturally erased means erased by natural phenomena of our environment. as you can see spell checker is coded to do so, it is not a natural process but a man hardcoded problem...

Comment: @SayedMohdAli it is the "nature" of the spell checker to be erased when the appropriate fix is applied to the text

Comment: @greystuff naturally erased means natural it is not nature(spell checker are computer coded program)... but I will say well try... if you see the answer of nudge-nudge sound suits the riddle.

Comment: @SayedMohdAli  I agree that NudgeNudge's answer is a lot better and most likely the correct one. I, however, cannot agree with your definition of natural which is far too restrictive especially for a puzzling community.

Comment: That's unfortunately not the correct answer, but also an interesting approach. I especially like the interpretation of "occurring inadvertently" in that context.